# How to point subdomain in AWS Route 53 under DNS management

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I have one public domain in AWS name is cloud.in there is a CNAME record in which the Value i need to change or point to another subdomain.

here is the screenshot of CNAME record hosted in route53 AWS

[image: DNS Record details]

Here is some information on domains

```
Old subdomain register in aws route53 :- test.cloud.in (main domain is cloud.in)
new subdomain register in godaddy     :- webui.cloud.in (main domain is cloud.in)
Live domain should point from webui.cloud.in to test.cloud.in same in CNAME record existing one in AWS route53
```

so when someone or customer hit test.cloud.in it should point to webui.cloud.in

Because test.cloud.in used in Route53 AWS and webui.cloud.in used or configure in GKE cluster

please let me know how can i do that
And i try to add ip address in webui.cloud.in CNAME record of under value test.cloud.in but its not working

And we are not using any cloudfront service in AWS

Comment: If you're not using Cloudfront, then why does your picture of a record show a Cloudfront URL?

Comment: The real question is which service -- AWS or GKE or GoDaddy -- is the authority for the `cloud.in` domain? That's where you have to define your CNAME.

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether `test.cloud.in` is itself a sub-domain. You can't use CNAME for the top-level entry of a subdomain (ie, if you have domain `example.com`, you can't create a CNAME that points `example.com` to `example.net`).

Comment: yes in picture it show Cloudfront that i dont know from where it got and who create that  and cloud.in is authority in godaddy that added as a hosted zones route53 same domain  i cannot add in CNAME its has value i need to add either webui.cloud.in or ip address of webui.cloud.in which is not working. Yes test.cloud.in is subdomain if cannot create then let me know what i can do